# Prerequisites for Freedman's proof of the 4-dimensional Poincaré conjecture

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I have a good understanding of differential geometry, enough at least to understand many details of Hamilton & Perelman's approach to the 3-dimensional Poincaré conjecture. I have no such understanding of Freedman's work, not even enough to be able to identify what I don't know. Where can I begin? I understand algebraic topology on about the level of Hatcher (I realize this isn't very much).

Answer (score 5):

Edit 11/21/2023:
As was pointed out in the comments, there is now a really wonderful reference for the Disk Embedding Theorem, a main ingredient in Freedman's proof. See The Disc Embedding Theorem, published in 2021 by Oxford University Press. It is the result of many hundreds of hours of work and many dedicated authors who put an incredible amount of effort into understanding Freedman's arguments and carefully explicating them.

Original answer:

That's a tall order! I would wager that very few people understand Freedman's proof completely. I found [this](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/4436) series of video lectures that he gave to be quite helpful. In particular, it will give you an idea about the sort of mathematics that is involved.

Also, Freedman and Quinn's book on $4$-manifold topology is great! Even if you aren't to the point where you can follow it in detail, you can still benefit from skimming through it.

Comment: I'd say "very few" is less than 10.

Comment: Mike Freedman, Frank Quinn...

Comment: Krushkal, Strong. Maybe Teichner. Most likely, nobody else.

Comment: Slava Krushkal definitely understands a lot of it, but he told me he hasn't been through the whole proof. Bob Edwards understands it of course.

Comment: I find that very surprising! For comparison's sake how many people would you estimate have a complete understanding of Perelman or Smale's work?

Comment: Smale's proof is much simpler. Milnor's book mentioned by Studiosus has a complete proof. Perelman's work is technical and doesn't use topological techniques. I really have no idea how many people understand all of its details, but I think more than Freedman's proof.

Comment: Now that the Disc Embedding Theorem book came out, perhaps one can think it to be >30 people?

Comment: @viniciuscantocosta Absolutely! Will edit to include.

Answer (score 4):

Start by reading Milnor's "Lectures on h-cobordism theorem", since Freedman's proof is a very difficult variation on Smale's proof in higher dimensions.